# SQL Server connection error (a weird one) (unsolved yet)

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server can be connected from local system but can not be connected from remote system in the network. The error code is 40 from Visual Studio and 1326 when I try to connect to SQL Server from Management Studio.

- Firewall isn't the problem
- TCP/IP connection is enabled from SQL Server
- There are 2 pc terminals that can connect to the SQL Server but the 3th one cannot and using the same connection strings so the connection string is right

It is SQL server 2000

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting from ODBC (Control panel, admin, odbc, new user connection).  Try creating a connection and test it at the end of the wizard.  If it works, then the problem has something to do with your OLEDB connection string, etc.
Otherwise, it could be

- a DNS issue (when you ping, make sure the correct IP address comes back)
- a server permissions issue (see if you can map a drive to the SQL Server and try your connection again)
- a SQL Permission issue (check the SQL security panel, make sure the user as db_reader permission (minimum) to his/her default database)
- a bad SQL Alias (in the ODBC wizard, under connection information, make sure the server name is only listed once.  If it is in there multiple times, you can install the SQL Client Configuration tools and remove all extra SQL Server aliases, which might be redirecting the [server name] to a different machine or invalid protocol by default).

Answer (score 1):

try to ping the server from the third terminal to see if the connection is on between them

Comment: yes there is! I did ping but everything seems fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few reasons with error 40.  Look [here for more information.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, check that you can ping the SQL Server from the 3rd box.

Also, check that the same version of MDAC are installed on the client that is on the server.

[See this article for a other fixes](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/09/sql-server-fix-error-1326-cannot-connect-to-database-server-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

Comment: I am not sure what version of MDAC are installed on the client! I will make sure that they have the same version. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Both errors 40 and 1326 suggest a named pipe error, not a TCP error. Since you mention that your server has TCP enabled, but you say nothing about named pipes, I suggest you take named pipes out of the equation. If you don't explicitly disable named pipes, the clients will always attempt this protocol first, and hit various errors as named pipes require SMB connectivity and domain authentication at the file sharing layer *before* even reaching the SQL Server. You have two avenues:

- disable named pipes completely on the client. See [Configuring Client Network Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190425.aspx).
- force tcp in the connection string, use the `tcp:servername` syntax for the server name part in the connection string, see [How to use the server name parameter in a connection string to specify the client network library](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313295).